# How cricket analyst store information of first 7 order lowest score table also?

Tags: cricket, statistics

Sports channel displayed **First 7 order lowest score table of INDIA**, showing lowest runs made on 7th fall of wicket. How did they manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "in a database". Assuming you've done the hard work of getting it all into the database in an appropriate form, it will be as simple as (in psuedo SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM wicket_falls WHERE wicket = 7 AND team = 'India' ORDER BY score
```

The other possibility is to use ESPN Cricinfo's "stats machine", but I'm rubbish at driving that so can't give you a like right now.